# association mapping entity delete check

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities with many-to-one association mapping.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ShopType")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShopTypeRepository")
 */
class ShopType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $shtId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shtName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $shtCreateuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="DateTime")
     */
    private $shtCreatedate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $shtModifyuid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="DateTime")
     */
    private $shtModifydate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $shtdelete;

    /**
     * One Shop Type has Many Shops.
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Shop", mappedBy="shtId")
     */
    private $shids;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->shids = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set shtId
     *
     * @param string $shtId
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtId($shtId)
    {
        $this->shtId = $shtId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getshtId()
    {
        return $this->shtId;
    }

    /**
     * Set shtName
     *
     * @param string $shtName
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtName($shtName)
    {
        $this->shtName = $shtName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getShtName()
    {
        return $this->shtName;
    }

    /**
     * Set shtCreateuid
     *
     * @param integer $shtCreateuid
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtCreateuid($shtCreateuid)
    {
        $this->shtCreateuid = $shtCreateuid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtCreateuid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getShtCreateuid()
    {
        return $this->shtCreateuid;
    }

    /**
     * Set shtCreatedate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $shtCreatedate
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtCreatedate($shtCreatedate)
    {
        $this->shtCreatedate = $shtCreatedate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtCreatedate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getShtCreatedate()
    {
        return $this->shtCreatedate;
    }

    /**
     * Set shtModifyuid
     *
     * @param integer $shtModifyuid
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtModifyuid($shtModifyuid)
    {
        $this->shtModifyuid = $shtModifyuid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtModifyuid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getShtModifyuid()
    {
        return $this->shtModifyuid;
    }

    /**
     * Set shtModifydate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $shtModifydate
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtModifydate($shtModifydate)
    {
        $this->shtModifydate = $shtModifydate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtModifydate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getShtModifydate()
    {
        return $this->shtModifydate;
    }

    /**
     * Set shtdelete
     *
     * @param string $shtdelete
     * @return ShopType
     */
    public function setShtDelete($shtdelete)
    {
        $this->shtdelete = $shtdelete;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shtdelete
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getshtDelete()
    {
        return $this->shtdelete;
    }
}
```

This is shoptype entity.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Shop")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShopRepository")
 */
class Shop
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $shId;


     /**
     * Many Features have One Product.
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ShopType", inversedBy="shids")
     * @JoinColumn(name="shtId", referencedColumnName="sht_id")
     */
    private $shtId;
```

When I delete shop type, I want to check it is used in shop. How can I check? My deletion in shop type is not really delete in database, just change the sht_delete flag 0 to 1. So , I want to know shop is used specific shop type, if so, I just show message "this shop type cannot be delete.". Thanks , for your time.

Comment: How do you set your ``shtdelete` flag to 1? Is the setter `setShtDelete` directly called? Is it done through a form?

Comment: not sure if this answer is what you are looking for but you could add a method to ShopType: hasShops() { return (bool) count($this->shids); }